# Find out if a particular commit exists on a git branch

Tags: git, git-svn

I see a commit in `foo` branch's log.  I'd like to determine if that commit has been cherry-picked onto branch `bar`.

If I were in a pure git environment I think the hashes would be the same, but the branch in question was pulled in using git-svn.

Comment: When the commits are on two different branches they will *not* have the same commit ID.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try "`git cherry`" or "`git patch-id`".

Answer (score 3):

I think the idiomatic answer would be `git branch --contains <commit_id>` and you could use `branch -r` to check the remote ones for the commit.